# How do you change the colors of cones in plotly R?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I have this vector field and would like to color the cones based on speed instead of whatever this default coloring is:

[image]

Repex Code and Data:

```
plot_dat <- structure(list(vb = structure(c(-3.02, -115.799, 203.187, 1, 
-0.715, -115.701, 202.444, 1, -3.024, -114.397, 201.275, 1, -2.058, 
-116.181, 203.556, 1, 4.437, -116.153, 205.384, 1, 4.471, -114.791, 
210.117, 1, 12.443, -105.538, 198.121, 1, 4.985, -107.238, 192.985, 
1, 5.458, -107.907, 193.987, 1, 5.061, -115.557, 207.515, 1, 
6.809, -114.172, 208.797, 1, 5.8, -115.493, 205.988, 1, 4.943, 
-111.077, 198.177, 1), dim = c(4L, 13L)), material = list(), 
    normals = NULL, texcoords = NULL, meshColor = "vertices", 
    it = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 
    1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    7L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 
    12L, 6L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 
    13L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 
    13L, 5L), dim = c(3L, 22L))), class = c("mesh3d", "shape3d"
))

cones <- structure(c(-0.09, -0.69, 0.383, 0.323, 0.588, 0.136, 0.097, 
0.169, 0.592, 0.058, 0.536, 0.611, 0.086, -0.994, -0.135, 0.871, 
-0.914, 0.738, 0.989, 0.703, 0.172, -0.64, 0.198, 0.842, 0.69, 
-0.971, -0.064, 0.711, 0.306, 0.244, -0.329, 0.058, -0.705, 0.971, 
0.491, -0.979, -0.064, -0.388, 0.224), dim = c(13L, 3L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("u", "v", "w")))

speed <- c(0.114, 0.02, 0.55, 0.514, 0.064, 0.296, 0.017, 0.634, 0.537, 
0.735, 0.339, 0.485, 0.921)

plot_ly() |>
  add_trace(
    type="cone",
    name = "CV Vectors",
    x = plot_dat$vb[1,],
    y = plot_dat$vb[2,],
    z = plot_dat$vb[3,],
    u = cones[,1],
    v = cones[,2],
    w = cones[,3],
        sizemode= 'absolute',
    sizeref= 2,
    hovertext = ~paste0("Speed (m/s) ", 
                        round(speed, 3))
  )
```

I've reviewed the [reference docs link description here](https://plotly.com/r/reference/cone/), but the only thing I can find for color is for things like the axes, different colorscale, etc. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you can do with color. Here are a few options.

The information for the argument `colorscale` (in the link you provided) includes a list of by name color gradients you can choose from. In this plot, I've assigned the scale to `"Portland"`.

```
plot_ly(type = "cone", name = "CV Vectors",
        colorscale = "Portland",
        x = plot_dat$vb[1,], y = plot_dat$vb[2,], z = plot_dat$vb[3,],
        u = cones[,1], v = cones[,2], w = cones[,3], sizemode= 'absolute',
        sizeref= 2, hovertext = ~paste0("Speed (m/s) ", round(speed, 3)))
```

[image]

Another option is to assign your own gradient. In this plot, I've assigned three colors to the values 0, .5, and 1. Think of the top of your color bar as 1, the bottom as 0, and whatever you assign the middle color, that's the middle of the color scale (whether that's .5 or .99 or anything else between 0 and 1).

```
plot_ly(type = "cone", name = "CV Vectors",
        colorscale = list(list(0, "#008080"), 
                          list(.5, "#F6EEE3"),
                          list(1, "#152238")),
        x = plot_dat$vb[1,], y = plot_dat$vb[2,], z = plot_dat$vb[3,],
        u = cones[,1], v = cones[,2], w = cones[,3], sizemode= 'absolute',
        sizeref= 2, hovertext = ~paste0("Speed (m/s) ", round(speed, 3)))
```

[image]

In this plot, I've used the same information as the previous plot, but I've changed that .5 to 0.8.

```
plot_ly(type = "cone", name = "CV Vectors",
        colorscale = list(list(0, "#008080"), 
                          list(.8, "#F6EEE3"),
                          list(1, "#152238")),
        x = plot_dat$vb[1,], y = plot_dat$vb[2,], z = plot_dat$vb[3,],
        u = cones[,1], v = cones[,2], w = cones[,3], sizemode= 'absolute',
        sizeref= 2, hovertext = ~paste0("Speed (m/s) ", round(speed, 3)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is all very helpful but the key feature I'm looking for is to color the arrows based on the values in the speed data, is that possible? So with the first colorscale, blue being slow/low speed and red being fast/high speed

Comment: Short answer: not with Plotly. Long answer: Plotly assigns color by the magnitude of a cone's velocity...(how fast they're moving over time). Your vector fields, `u`, `v`, & `w`, represent the angular momentum of what you've measured. Your cones have nearly identical magnitudes. While you've assigned speeds, these values don't seem to represent the data you're plotting. If your vectors represent the angular momentum, I think you'd be able to assign the colors you want. (Magnitude: `sqrt(u * u + v * v + w * w)`)